# Testing communication protocols (Bluetooth, WiFi, USB)

Tags: tool-recommend, protocols

At my job, we create some multimedia unit with communication capabilities (Bluetooth, WiFi, USB).

**How can we test the implementation of these communication protocols** in a reliable / "certifiable" way? What SW / HW is recommended?

We can do basic testing by just pairing that unit with smartphones, but then we do not have a "certification" for the phones either. Also, I am not aware how to automate the process when using smartphones.

Considering the amount of test-cases, automation is definitely welcome.

---

Update: I am not aware of any need to obtain certifications.

Comment: Following your edit- what DO you need ? why are you concerned about testing more than a smoke test ?

Comment: We want to provide a good experience, without (or at least minimizing) problems. Just a smoke test is likely to be far from what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a huge question, let's break it down a bit (I'll answer about Wi-Fi but the same applies for USB and Bluetooth).

The first thing you need to investigate is what are your needs.

Any WiFi equipment needs to be certified by the [WiFi alliance](https://www.wi-fi.org/), [the certification](https://emcfastpass.com/rf-modules/) can be done at the Hardware module that you use or the entire product so your first question would be- do I need an official certification of my product.

Since the term WiFi is a trademark, then a product using it is bound to be certified. If you want to be extra careful you can search the product database at the WiFi alliance.

Your next question would be "do we use ready made components or not", it is very common to use ready made modules the comes with software drivers and reference design. You common operating systems (Windows, Linux, Android) will take care of the rest. When using a ready made component you can limit your tests, unless there's a special reason you want to be extra careful.

WiFi is tested at the (with links to relevant test equipment):

- [Physical level and Protocol testing](https://www.spirent.com/products/wi-fi-automate-test-system)
- [High level protocol](https://www.ixiacom.com/products/ixchariot)
- [Wi Fi certification](https://www.wi-fi.org/certification/wi-fi-test-suite)

And you can test at the application level using standard software testing tools that will treat WiFi as just another network on the way, and the WiFi settings as just another UI element you test.

Note 1- The WiFi standard is huge and allows some freedom in the implementation, this means that coming up with your test plan would be very hard and time consuming, on the other hand buying test equipment or software is very expensive and still needs a lot of knowledge and time to be operated.

Note 2- As I said above the same applies for [USB compliance](https://www.usb.org/compliance) and [Bluetooth](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/)